# Telling SqlAlchemy to map a column but not insert or update its values

Tags: python, sql-server, orm, sqlalchemy

I have columns in my database that the database manages. I want SqlAlchemy to map these and retrieve their values in the read operation but not send anything to them in the create or update operations since the database itself manages those. How do I achieve that?  Here are details:

Here is my SQL Server ddl:

```
create table "foo" (
    "id" int identity not null primary key,
    "name" varchar(40) not null, 
    "whenCreated" datetime2(7) not null default (SYSUTCDATETIME()),
    "rowVersion" rowversion)
```

running sqlacodegen generates:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(40, 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'), nullable=False, unique=True)
    whenCreated = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=text("(sysutcdatetime())"))
    rowVersion = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
```

running this code:

```
session = Session()
def test(self):
    #create foo
    f = Foo(name='test')
    Test_crud.session.add(f)
    Test_crud.session.commit()
```

Throws the following exception:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pyodbc.IntegrityError) ('23000',
>   '[23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot
>   insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a
>   column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into
>   the timestamp column. (273) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][SQL
>   Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be
>   prepared. (8180)') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO [foo] (name, [rowVersion])
>   OUTPUT inserted.id VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('test', None)]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)

I have tried modifying the python object in these two ways and still get the same error.

```
rowVersion = Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)
rowVersion = Column(TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the following [Documentation page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#rowcount-support-orm-versioning) and this (`or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column`) part of the error message you can do the following:

```
rowVersion = Column(TIMESTAMP(), default=text('DEFAULT'))
```

Comment: Thanks!That didn't work but this did:    

    rowVersion = Column(TIMESTAMP(), server_default=text('DEFAULT'))